# Question about C# and function prototypes

Tags: c#

I was looking at the `TextReader` class, but I only see method prototypes, I can't see the definitions anywhere. I'm interested in how things work under the hood and I tried looking for the definition of `public void Dispose();` but trying to peek or go to definition in VS2019 just returns me here. Where are they stored?

How is it possible to prototype like this? I tried doing it and it wouldn't allow me. This particular method is not virtual.

Comment: There are no prototypes in C#. Check out reference source, or git hub for the source code

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,7b5eff52b5bf1164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing by "method prototypes" you mean the *headers* of the methods, i.e. these things:

```
public virtual Task<String> ReadLineAsync()
```

The *body* of the method (or in your words, "definition") is not shown in Visual Studio. One place you can find them, is https://referencesource.microsoft.com/. For example, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib,namespaces) is the source for `TextReader`.

Note that `TextReader` is an *abstract class*. Some of the methods in an abstract class can have no bodies *by design* (though this is not the case with `TextReader`). For an interface, all methods have no bodies<sup>*</sup>. If you want to see the implementations of those abstract methods, you need to go to a concrete implementation. For `TextReader`, this could be `StreamReader`.

You can create these so called "prototypes" by creating an interface (though it's not the same kind of thing as the one you see in `TextReader`):

```
interface IFoo {
    int Method1(string param);
    string Method2(string p1, string p2);
    ...
}
```